# C# FTP Upload Server returned an error: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Hi I'm trying to upload a file with a passed in byte[] and am getting a 550.

I'm using a Memory stream in a using statement so I thought it should close itself off nicely.

If I'm dealing with a byte array rather than a physical file what could be causing the lock as the byte array doesn't map to a file per-say it is generated by a csv helper.

Basically I build up a csv with a stringbuilder and the call Export which takes the string builder and puts it in to a byte[] which then gets passed in to this method..

Just wondering if anyone could see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

```
 bool PutFileToServer(string remoteFile, byte[] bytesToUpload, bool result)
    {
        try
        {
            LogStatus("Creating FTP Request");
            var ftpRequest = CreateRequest(remoteFile, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile);

            using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream(bytesToUpload))
            using (var requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Position = 0;

                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesSent = dataStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

                LogStatus("Reading File Stream");
                try
                {
                    while (bytesSent != 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                        bytesSent = dataStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogStatus("Error Reading File Bytes");
                    LogStatus(ex.Message);
                    result = false;
                    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);

                    if (dataStream != null)
                    {
                        dataStream.Close();
                    }

                    if (requestStream != null)
                    {
                        requestStream.Close();
                    }

                    if (ftpStream != null)
                    {
                        ftpStream.Close();
                    }

                    ftpRequest = null;
                }

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogStatus(ex.Message);
            result = false;
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);

            if (ftpStream != null)
            {
                ftpStream.Close();
            }

            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process...
1. what else outside of the upload could be holding the file open stopping you from streaming it?
2.Check write perms exist on the folder your uploading to.

Comment: Hi Aaron thanks for the reply. But if I'm dealing with a byte array rather than a physical file what could be causing the lock as the byte array doesn't map to a file per-say it is generated by a csv helper. Basically I build up a csv with a stringbuilder and the call Export which takes the string builder and puts it in to a byte[] which then gets passed in to this method..